# AJAX+PHP+PHPExcel

Tags: php, ajax

boa tarde
Eu estou passando via ajax alguns campos do meu modal para uma função PHP. Desta forma, eu executo a query abaixo na função PHP para gerar uma planilha Excel.
o problema é que: eu até recebo os valores via POST no PHP mas dá erro na criação da planilha EXCEL. Ai se eu coloco o valor fixo na variavel,
a planilha é criada sem problemas.
Aonde estou errando neste caso ?

```
function exp_excel()
{
var url = "<?php echo site_url('ExpExcel/exportExcel')?>";

$.ajax({
    url : url,
    type: "POST",
    data: $('#form_1').serialize(),
    dataType: "HTML",   
    success: function(data)
    {
        window.location = url;
        $('#modal_excel').modal('hide');
    },
    error: function (request, status, erro) {

    },   
});
}

public function exportExcel()
{

//$gestor  = $_POST["NomeGestor"]; -> assim nao funciona
//$qtdDias = $_POST["qtdDias"]; 

$gestor  = "Francisco Jose"; -> assim funciona normal
$qtdDias = "3"; 


try{

$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_dpo_1 WHERE 
          gestor LIKE '{$gestor}' AND (data_oper >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE() ,INTERVAL {$qtdDias} DAY) 
          AND data_oper <= CURRENT_DATE())  AND (operacao LIKE 'UPD_REG' OR operacao LIKE 'NEW_REG')";

$resultado = mysql_query($query);

//CRIA O OBJETO PARA EXPORTAR PARA O EXCEL
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');

$data = date('dmy');
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="DPO-Consolidado_'. $data .".xlsx");
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
}
```

Comment: Bruno, a indicação "NomeGestor" está no campo "name" do formulário?

Comment: Uma sugestão também seria usar nomes de variáveis minúsculas. Outra coisa que vi estar diferente do que fiz foi a indicação do dataType. Eu coloquei "html" (tudo em minúsculo), não sei se isso afetaria alguma coisa.

Comment: Fala Rodrigo, eu vou mudar para minusculo. este campo esta no modal: <select class="form-control" name="NomeGestor" id="NomeGestor"> e vou mudar tambem o html para minusculo.

Comment: eu mudei lá mas não resolveu não. passando as variaveis, ele até dispara o download da planilha, mas dá o erro: "o Excel não pode abrir o arquivo 'DPO-Consolidado_110718.xlsx. por que o formato ou a extensão de arquivo não é valida." e se eu deixo o valor fixo, ele faz o download da planilha normalmente com os registros.

Comment: Bruno, coloque dentro da função exportaExcel do PHP um var_dump($_POST); para forçar exibir o que ele está recebendo do Ajax... Será que o erro está ao receber os dados pelo Post e, ao montar o Select, ele não encontra o nome no banco? Mais uma coisa, tente trocar o LIKE por = ao fazer a comparação direta.

Comment: Rodrigo, o dump saiu assim: <pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<b>array</b> <i>(size=2)</i>
  'nome_gestor' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'Francisco Jose'</font> <i>(length=15)</i>
  'qtdDias' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'3'</font> <i>(length=1)</i>. fiz um teste com = na query mas da o mesmo problema. na minha função estou passando o post assim:           
         $gestor  = $_POST["nome_gestor"];
 $qtdDias = $_POST["qtdDias"];

Comment: Uma forcinha ai galera? to precisando bastante resolver isso. muito obrigado.

Comment: Bruno, essa tá desafiadora. Eu desconfio que alguma coisa tá errada ao montar o Select com os dados vindos do POST. Talvez esteja faltando aspas, ou tenha aspas demais... faça um var_dump($query); pra ver como ele está montando o Select com os dados vindos do POST pra ver.

Comment: Já conseguiste resolver?

Comment: Consegui nada White. já testei de tudo e não vai pra frente

Comment: Rodrigo é muito estranho, pois, quando eu disparo o metodo ajax, no retorno, ele me traz o select no dump e mais os valores que preciso da query. porém logo depois, ocorre erro de PHP dizendo que os campos que estou passando são indefinidos.

Comment: Alguém teria alguma ideia do que pode estar errado ?